# Joi validation errors using allow('')

Tags: joi

I've come out with a Joi schema that validates data to data5, however, it also validates data6 which is not what I want as it should error.

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  a: [Joi.string()],
  b: [Joi.string()],
  c: Joi.string().required().allow('')
}).with('a', 'c')
  .with('b', 'c');

const data = {
  a: 'true',
  b: 'true',
  c: 'some str'
};

const data2 = {
  a: 'true',
  c: 'some str'
};

const data3 = {
  b: 'true',
  c: 'some str'
};

const data4 = {
  c: 'some str'
};

const data5 = {
  c: ''
};

const result = Joi.validate(dataX, schema, { abortEarly: false });
```

I'm trying to get this to error but it validates due to the .allow('')

```
const data6 = {
  a: 'true',
  b: 'true',
  c: ''
};
```

If I remove the .allow() then it works, however, data5 then errors.

How can I change the schema so it errors data6 but continues to validate data to data5.

Cheers,

Paul